# Lewis form factor in between teeth

Tags: dynamics

I’ve got total gear ratio of 3.428 but it’s a double step up gearbox. So I have to sq root it get the ratio of the pairs which is 1.851. For the small cog I have to use a min of 18 teeth. So teeth x g = 33.326. How can I get a real gear ratio? I’m not sure on if I round the 33 down or up to 34. As I don’t have 33 on my Lewis form factor. For the assignment I have 30 and 34 on form factor. I’m not sure what to use. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So use a whole number of teeth ie integer. Then work out the numbers given a starting point like the 34 you suggest.

Comment: Hi Mike, even if I use for example 20 teeth it works out as 20 x 1.851 = 37.02. Which is the same problem with 18 teeth it doesn’t give me the Y value for it on my table as I have values for (30,34,38etc).  So I can’t use it for the calculations.

Comment: Well, had a differential with a ratio of 4.78:1 and there were an integer number of teeth. Swapped that for a differential of 3.54:1 and that also had an integer number of teeth. In fact having stripped, repaired and built many gearboxes I have never seen a fractional tooth on any gear - except broken ones...

Comment: I’m not questioning the amount of teeth on a real life application can’t be fractional or decimal. I’m just confused when my nearest integer is 33 and I don’t have any values for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its for an assignment then, you shouldn't worry too much.
One solution is to use the 34 (which has a Lewis factor)

Another is to do an **interpolation** between the lewis factor for 30 and 34

Yet Another is to find out other tables/equation that allow you calculate the factor for 33.  E.g. there is an online calculator at [engineersedge](https://www.engineersedge.com/gears/lewis-factor.htm)